# How does the ki point bonus advancement work for monk vows?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, character-levels

I would like to use the [optional rule](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/monk-vows/) for taking vows as a monk, from the Ultimate Magic rulebook.

My player took the [vow of poverty](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/monk-vows/vow-of-poverty/) which grants 1 ki point for every monk level. Crystal clear. But he took also the [vow of fasting](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/monk-vows/vow-of-fasting/), with a ki point bonus of 1 every 6 levels with a minimum of +1.

It is unclear to me whether:

- It is as stated and my player will gain a ki point every 6 levels with a mimimum of +1, meaning he will have +1 from him taking the vow until level 11, +2 from level 12 to 17, +3 from level 18 ;
- My player gains a fraction of 1/6 ki point per level rounded to +1 if the monk is level 1 to 5.

When I took a glance at reddit ([this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/3fpl2q/monk_wants_to_take_every_single_vow_certain/ctqts54?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) in particular), the general comprehension is that it works as a fraction at every level, working like the class of predilection special bonus. And that would mean that the fractional bonus of a class of predilection bonus would stack with the vow bonus. And it would easily be a headache:

If the player gains 1/4 ki point per level from his class of predilection bonus, plus a 1/6 ki point from his vow, he would in fact gain 10/24 ki points per level. With a minimum of +1 from the vow. Easy to count, right?

I plan on using the first rule, although the ki point bonus growth is very odd, but I may have missed some rule or something...

What is the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither the player nor the GM needs to determine a fractional advancement for [monk vows](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/monk-vows/) because the monk vows already detail how they advance.

For example, when the benefit of the monk vow [Vow of Fasting](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/monk-vows/vow-of-fasting/) says, "A monk with this vow increases his *ki* pool by 1 *ki* point for every 6 monk levels (minimum +1)," it means that when the creature possesses from 1 to 11 monk levels the creature gains 1 *ki* point from the Vow of Fasting, from 12 to 17 monk levels 2 *ki* points, and 18 or more monk levels 3 *ki* points.

For example, when the benefit of the monk vow [Vow of Celibacy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/monk-vows/vow-of-celibacy/) says, "A monk with this vow increases his *ki* pool by 1 *ki* point for every 5 monk levels (minimum +1)," it means that when the creature possesses from 1 to 9 monk levels the creature gains 1 *ki* point from the Vow of Celibacy, from 10 to 14 monk levels 2 *ki* points, from 15 to 19 monk levels 3 *ki* points, and 20 or more monk levels 4 *ki* points.

In short, extra *ki* points from monk vows are gained based on each vow's individual schedule then summed. For example, a level 1 monk with both of the above vows gains +2 *ki* points, while a level 15 monk with both of the above vows gains +5 *ki* points (i.e. +2 from Fasting and +3 from celibacy).

With all due respect to that *Reddit* comment, monk vows don't work like favored class bonuses which do, in fact, see their bonuses increase fractionally due to special rules about how they stack. (See also [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80371/8610).) Instead, monk vows work exactly just like they say they work, no fractions necessary.